# Is there a Method to read the Content of a Website?

Tags: c#, automation, web-crawler, webclient

I wanted to write a Program that reads an online Calendar, compares it with Names in a Database and uses this Data in some way. But if I use the WebClient, it reads the Source Code of the Website, not the Content. This is my Code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace CalendarCrawler
{
    class Program
    {

        static void KillTask(string Task)
        {
            Process[] Process = new Process[] { };
            Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(Task);
            foreach (Process Instance in Process)
            {
                Instance.Kill();
            }

            
        }
        static String ReadContent(String Website)
        {
            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            System.IO.Stream stream = web.OpenRead(Website);
            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                String text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return text;
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting Connection ...");

            var datasource = "localhost";//your server

            var database = "database"; //your database name
            var username = "username"; //username of server to connect
            var password = "password"; //password

            //your connection string 
            string connStr = $"Server={datasource};Database={database};Uid={username};Pwd={password}";
            //create instanace of database connection
            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Openning Connection ...");

                    //open connection
                    conn.Open();

                    Console.WriteLine("Connection successful!");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
                String Websitetext = ReadContent("http://www.esel.at/termine");
                var stm = $"INSERT INTO content(Content) VALUES (@1);";
                var cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", Websitetext);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               
                Console.WriteLine(Websitetext);
                KillTask("CalendarCrawler");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Killtask Method is only to Clear it from the Background Processes, so there are no Problems with building a new Version.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I would suggest to use thr newer HttpClient to do http request. The source is the content. What you must do is parse the source code and there are plenty of libearies for that.

Comment: Have a look at HtmlAgilityPack: https://html-agility-pack.net/

Comment: What are you meaning by "Source Code" vs "Content" here? it is just going to read HTML, surely? that *is* the content...

Comment: Using `WebClient` to retrieve website content is very likely to hit a roadblock as soon as JavaScript is involved. If possible avoid web scraping at all cost and use any available API. Else, use HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: I guess by "content" you mean rendered text?

Comment: If your website is generated fully or partially dynamically (by JavaScript that queries the server to render the actual content, for example) you will not be able to scrape the content with anything short of something that actually implements a full browser stack -- something like node.js, Selenium or a browser extension.

Comment: @af2111 what do you call `source code` **is the content**. What you see *is* that HTML source code - unless that web site is an SPA with Javascript code that requests data from the server and displays it at runtime. To get the same output you'd have to execute the Javascript too. You'd need either a browser for it, or an HTML parser that actually executes Javascript

Comment: One possibility is to use Selenium to automate a browser and retrieve the displayed DOM objects once the Javascript code executes. Another possibility is to use [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/docs/Examples.html#connecting-javascript-evaluation), which includes a Javascript engine.

Comment: It looks like the website has an API. For example, it sends get request with url "https://esel.at/api/termine/data?date=08.07.2020&selection=false" and the request returns JSON. Maybe you should try to send same requests?

Answer (score 0):

There are effectively 2 different users of the web.  People and computers.   People like shiney things like buttons and tables (UI), computers prefer things like XML or JSON (API).

Your calendar web site has a UI, this is what you are currently seeing (both in a browser and when you 'download the code').  It probably has an API too and that is what you should be using in your program.

I've just had a quick look at [esel.at](https://esel.at) and it doesn't appear to have a (public) API (but maybe that is because Google can't translate the page properly).